# Combining two functions together so both work

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to combine two functions together so they both simultaneously. How can I do this?

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function showTicks()
{
    if (chooseShield.value == ("ely"))
    {
        document.getElementById("cb1").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("cb2").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("cb3").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("cb4").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("cb5").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("cb6").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("cb7").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("cb8").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("cb9").disabled=true;   
    }
}

function checkchecks() 
{
    if(likeShield.value == ("noShield") && chooseShield.value == ("ely") && (cb3.checked   == true || cb4.checked == true))
    {
        document.getElementById("cb2").checked=true;
    }

    likeShield.onchange=checkchecks
    chooseShield.onchange=checkchecks
    cb3.onchange=checkchecks
    cb4.onchange=checkchecks
}

  function doBoth() {
  checkAll();
  checkchecks();
}
likeShield.onchange=doBoth;
chooseShie;d.onchange=doBoth;
cb3.onchange=doBoth;
cb4.onchange=doBoth;
```

The first function disables all the checkboxes except 1, 2, 3 and 4. The second function should then allow a user to click 3 or 4 which would automatically check checkbox 2. But only the second function works and the first one is ignored. The `onchange = "showTicks()"` in the html.

Comment: Semicolons are not optional. And neither is indentation. And please never write `== true`.

Comment: Code is much cleaner without them. They are absolutely optional in most cases. [An Open Letter to JavaScript Leaders Regarding Semicolons](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Comment: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/ It's a matter of preference to use semicolons or not. Indentation would be nice though

Comment: @minitech - *Theoretically* semicolons are indeed optional. In most cases, its nice to have them there. If you're going to run your code through a minifier, they are going to insert them anyway.

Comment: @techfoobar: I know they're "optional" but no good code omits semicolons so I just say they're not optional on Stack Overflow and it gets the point across. :)

Comment: This is the third version of about the same question, each time with little additions. That's not how you should use SO. I hope we'll find this time what is blocking you.

Comment: @minitech, oh, I didn't knew that you're world authority and you have golden standard of good code at your home.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
var doBoth = function(){
      showTicks();
      checkchecks();
};
likeShield.onchange=doBoth;
chooseShield.onchange=doBoth;
cb3.onchange=doBoth;
cb4.onchange=doBoth;
```

Another option would be to use addEventListener :

```
likeShield.addEventListener('change', showTicks);
likeShield.addEventListener('change', checkchecks);
```

but it would be more verbose in your case.

Of course, if your two functions serve no other purpose, the simplest would be to take the code of the showTicks function and put it into the checkchecks function.

Also, don't forget to ensure variables like `chooseShield` are defined. Here's how you can define your variables :

```
var chooseShield = document.getElementById('chooseShield');
var likeShield = document.getElementById('likeShield');
for (var i=1; i<10; i++) window['cb'+i]=document.getElementById('cb'+i);
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/ey3e9/)

Comment: Hmm that does not seem to be working. Do i need to create another function for that. If so you edit my first post.

Comment: I updated the first post is that alright? Because its not functioning still. Could you correct please.

Comment: I made a demonstration. You really should be able to go with this this time.

Comment: Ok what should the onchange be on the HTML? 

onchange="showTicks()" for both?

Comment: Don't put onchange in the HTML (I just edited the fiddle to remove them). Just have the 'change' event listener defined in the script.

Comment: Sorry but what is the change event listener and where do I put it

Comment: The line "likeShield.onchange=doBoth;" tells the browser to call the doBoth function when the select's value change.

Comment: So do I leave the onchange blank on the HTML. Or do I add something

Comment: No. Remove completely the "onchange=" from the html. Just like in my fiddle.

Comment: I am using an external js file if you didnt know